# How many prints had been accured via crystalreport in VB6?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report viewer object in a VB form and I need to know how many times it was printed.
actually I want to know "how many times a user hit the print button on the crystal report object"

thanks

Comment: Can you simply count them in your program?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want you want to say

Comment: I will insert username into a table, then I can understand who, how many times printed the report.

Comment: OK. But do you print from your VB6 program using a CrystalReport control? If so why don't you just count all this prints in your program and then update information in your database?

Comment: no, I want to print it via Crystal report print button.

Answer (score 1):

The CrystalReportsViewer control has a PrintButtonClicked event within which you could keep a count. You will have to keep track of which report is currently being displayed in the reportviewer though.

Comment: great, but after that it shows a prompt to user. if user clicks on cancel button, the report wont be printed. is there any way to control it?